# parametric reflection of one curve across another

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametric, inverse-function, plane-curves

In this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238534/is-imposing-one-function-onto-another-ever-used-in-mathematics) the user asks for a parametric curve and "imposing" one curve on another. You can find a demonstration [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/imndeqknn7).

I have [been meaning to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813193/finding-the-plane-curve-resulting-from-a-reflection-onto-another-plane-curve) use the tangent to answer a similar question on how to find a reflected curve across another and have such a desmos demonstration. However I am not sure what the equations should turn out to be in that case.

By reflecting curve $F$ across $G$, I mean that for every point of $G$, we calculate the normal vector, and copying the intersection point between the normal line and curve $F$ at the same distance but on the opposite side of the curve $G$ along the normal direction. The resulting curve $F'$ of all those points is the "reflection" of $F$ along $G$.

This can also be thought of as a generalization of the function inverse. When we let the curve we are reflecting over be the $y=x$ line, the reflection $F'$ is precisely the inverse of the curve $F$, in the sense that the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the points have been swapped.

Comment: I suggest that you call this "reflecting $F$ **across** $G$" rather than **onto**, as the points generally don't land **on** $G$ at all, unless they began there, in which case they're fixed points.

Comment: That is a good suggestion and I took it. Hopefully we get some answers.

Comment: I have discussed a similar problem here in the comments; perhaps this may be helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849213/reflection-of-a-continuous-differentiable-curve-about-a-line

Comment: I think that might be worth a try. How did you find this method?